# Can't send image to server, getting "Error: Request failed with status code 500" while sending image file by axios in react native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I am using react native RNCamera. I am getting the file uri from the data retuned by react native RNCamera

Here is the code how I did that

```
const mimeType = mime.getType(damageImage.uri);
console.log('received image', damageImage.uri, mimeType);
//Here I am getting damageImage.uri as file:///data/user/0/com.tvsmobile/cache/Camera/2c32593e-5015-4ef1-b8b0-db141628444e.jpg
// and mime type: image/jpeg
try {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    formData.append('damage_image', {
        uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? damageImage.uri : damageImage.uri.replace('file://', ''),
        name: 'image.jpg',
        type: mimeType, //I tried by passing 'image/jpeg' here
    });

    let response = await axios.request({
        baseURL: base_url,
        method: 'post',
        url: headRoute + transactionRoute + damageRoute + 'add/',
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });
    return response.data;
} catch (e) {
    console.log('error at sending damage asset:' + e);
    const response = e.response;
    switch (response.status) {
        case 601:
        case 605:
        case 606:
            Snackbar.show({text: response.data.errMessage});
            break;
        default:
            Snackbar.show({text: defMsg});
            break;
    }
}
```

###### Any help will appreciate

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Did you try your api endpoint without React Native ?

Comment: can you try this` formData.append('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');` instead of jpeg try with jpg.. Once i got a issue by jpeg and by replacing it into jpg or png solved that issue

Comment: Ok, I will try that

Comment: @yousoumar No, I didn't tried

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 means an error has happened on the server side (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500), so by inspecting front-end code is rather difficult, if not impossible, to say what is the cause. If you are able, you should check the server logs to find the cause, which might or might not be caused by your data.